# Display returned integral containing assumptions with integral sign

Tags: differential-equations, calculus-and-analysis, output-formatting, assumptions

From solving the PDE example of the general 1 dim heat equation in Nasser Abbasi's site https://www.12000.org/my_notes/pde_in_CAS/maple_2019_and_mma_12/insu157.htm#x182-1810003.1.1 (his problem No 151) I get the described solution containing the integral

`Integrate[f[x] Sin[(\[Pi] x n)/L], {x, 0, L}, Assumptions -> k > 0 && L > 0]`

Instead of this output form, how can I display this integral with the integral sign, as it is displayed in Nasser's site, not showing the assumptions? Neither StandardForm nor TraditionalForm does this. Is taking out (e.g. manually) the assumptions from Integrate's arguments the only way? How can I have Mathematica output the solution with the integral displayed with the integral sign and without the assumptions? Can the assumptions (any assumptions) be taken out automatically from Integrate's arguments, e.g. by some kind of replacement? I can't find out what this general replacement rule would have to be.

Thanks for help!

Comment: "Is taking out (e.g. manually) the assumptions from `Integrate`'s arguments the only way?" - perhaps my definition of "manually" is a little different from yours, but: `Integrate[f[x] Sin[(Pi x n)/L], {x, 0, L}, Assumptions -> k > 0 && L > 0] /. HoldPattern[Integrate][fun_, Longest[int : ({__} ..)], rest___] :> Integrate[fun, int]`. If you wish, you could also employ `Inactive[]` somewhere.

Comment: @J.M. This answers my question. Thanks a lot.

Comment: @J.M. I don't think I understand your more elaborate pattern.  Probably I'm overlooking something important.  Would you mind explaining why it's needed?

Comment: You might also use `Interpretation`: `intForm[int : 
   Verbatim[Integrate][f_, x : Except[_Rule] .., opts___Rule]] :=
 Interpretation[
  HoldForm[Integrate[f, x]],
  int]`. Then `integral // intForm`.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard 1. I don't want `Integrate[]` on the LHS to evaluate. 2. I want the rule to also catch multivariate integrals like `Integrate[f[x] g[y + a], {x, 0, 1}, {y, 0, 1}, Assumptions -> (a > 0)]`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Depending on your needs consider [`$PrePrint`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/$PrePrint.html) and [`MakeBoxes`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/MakeBoxes.html).  Something like this:

```
MakeBoxes[
  Integrate[a__, Assumptions -> _],
  fmt : TraditionalForm
] := MakeBoxes[Integrate[a], fmt]
```

Now when you view the integral in [`TraditionalForm`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/TraditionalForm.html):

```
Integrate[f[x] Sin[(n π x)/L], {x, 0, L}, 
  Assumptions -> k > 0 && L > 0] // TraditionalForm
```

$$\int_0^L f(x) \sin \left(\frac{\pi  n x}{L}\right) \, dx$$

And [`TeXForm`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/TeXForm.html) works too because by default is uses `TraditionalForm`:

```
Integrate[f[x] Sin[(n π x)/L], {x, 0, L}, 
  Assumptions -> k > 0 && L > 0] // TeXForm
```

> ```
> \int_0^L f(x) \sin \left(\frac{\pi  n x}{L}\right)\, dx
> ```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer. This kind of global solution is indeed most appropriate for my needs.

Comment: @RolandSalz Happy to help.  Let me know if you have problem using this and I'll try to fix it.